# Wikipedia and official IPA symbol chart appear quite different

Tags: ipa

So I am learning the IPA. I am familiar with most of the manners and places thus far. However, I am not sure which consonant chart to reference. The 2 charts I am considering seem quite different, albeit I haven't gone over them with a fine comb to spot any overlap. Here they are:

http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-charts/ipa-symbols-chart-complete/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Consonants

So I intend to make flash cards of the IPA phonemes. Which chart would be most useful?

Comment: The one in Wiki is definitely better, it's fuller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the actually official charts from the IPA [here](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/content/full-ipa-chart). There is no reason to use unofficial and potentially error-ridden charts when you can use the real thing. The IPA is not just a list of letters, it is a system of symbols and terms. There are no stops in IPA -- they are called plosives. The Wiki page is wrong.

Comment: Another reason that "stop" is not a good name for this row in the chart is that "nasal" is used for a different row of consonants.  Yet the nasal consonants m, n, ... are generally classified as stops.

Comment: @user6726
`t͡ɕ` is on the wikipedia page, yet missing from the official chart (as are other symbols). Confused by this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_affricate

Comment: @user7276 stop and plosive are all synonyms it seems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_consonant

Comment: @zingbats, likewise, ʃ and š stand for the same sounds. However, only ʃ is IPA. It depends on how much of IPA you want to learn. You should learn the general meaning of the diacritics, not the specific list given by Wiki. The terminological mismatch between WikiPA and actual IPA is pretty huge.

Comment: @user6726 I want to learn the official IPA, so obviously I'll stick with the official source to save myself learning something unnecessary. It's just that I am greatly confused by this damn Wikipedia article. So, I've created a section on wiki talk page asking for a justification as to why the consonant chart is so vastly different to that of the official's. We'll see what is said.

Comment: @zingbats, you might want to read corresponding pages in other languages, just to see the charts. They are pretty variable as to content, not just translations of "plosief / plosive / plosiv / ffrwydrol / klusiili"

Comment: @user6726 Certainly an edifying suggestion. Much obliged